# question about brownian hit time and reflexion principle

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have a Brownian motion W(t)

I consider 2 events, where T is fixed :

A : W(T) is above a, a > 0

B : W(t) hit the level b, b < 0, at least once between 0 and T

I am trying to compute P(A and B)
This is comming from a book with several questions like this, with the hint being "use the reflexion principle"

Now, the reflexion principle helps me rephrashing either A or B, but doesn't help with the event (A and B ), as far as I can tell. I tried conditionning by either A or B but it doesn't reduce to something simple enough to be easily computed.

Does anyone know how to compute this probability  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau_b$ denote the first hitting time of $b\lt0$ by $W$, then the process reflected at $b$ is defined by $X(t)=W(t)$ for $t\leqslant\tau_b$ and $X(t)=2b-W(t)$ for $t\gt\tau_b$ and the reflexion principle asserts that $X$ is again a Brownian motion.

Then $A\cap B=[X(T)\lt2b-a]$ and, since $X(T)$ is distributed as $-\sqrt{T}\cdot W(1)$, one gets $$P(A\cap B)=P(W(1)\gt c)=\int_c^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx,\qquad c=\frac{a-2b}{\sqrt{T}}.$$

Comment: Hi,I get that the proba explained is event A, but where is event B included in your expression of A inter B ?

Comment: No the "proba explained" is W being above a *after having hit b*, which is equivalent to X being below b-(a-b)=2b-a. Every picture related to the reflection principle will show you the same thing, which ones did you look at?